# create Query in access

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

Customer Table

ECR Table

I have two tables(they are related in cif) and **i want to know how to** create those two query

**first one** to show all customer  id as cif in my table (1) whose status= closed and they have ECRstatus from second table = active

**second one** to show all customer whose status closed **doesn't have any** active ECR if he has one or more doesn't appear in this query and only appear in first one

Comment: What have you tried (please update your post with details), and what specific problem(s) did you run into?

Comment: i tried the first query and its work but i  dont know how to create second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these queries as SQL:

**ECR Status Active:**

```
SELECT Customer.CIF, Customer.CUS_STATUS, ECR.ECRStatus
FROM Customer INNER JOIN ECR ON Customer.CIF = ECR.ID_cif
WHERE (((Customer.CUS_STATUS)="closed") AND ((ECR.ECRStatus)="active"));
```

**ECR Status Inactive:**

```
SELECT Customer.CIF, Customer.CUS_STATUS, ECR.ECRStatus
FROM Customer INNER JOIN ECR ON Customer.CIF = ECR.ID_cif
WHERE (((Customer.CUS_STATUS)="closed") AND ((ECR.ECRStatus)<>"active"));
```